Having trouble proving a real analysis proposition
Suppose $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a measure space, and $(X,\mathcal{M}^*,\mu^*)$ is its smallest compeletion, i.e.,

$\mathcal{M}\subset\mathcal{M}^*$;
$\mu^*|_{\mathcal{M}}=\mu$;
any $\mu$-null set belongs to $\mathcal{M}^*$.

where $\mu$-null set is a subset of $X$ that can be contained within a set of measure zero with respect to $(\mathcal{M},\mu)$.It's easy to show that the exact expresion of this extension is:
$$\begin{align}\mathcal{M}^*&=\{A\cup S:A\in\mathcal{M},S\text{ is a }\mu\text{-null set}\},\\[2ex]\mathcal{M}^*&\stackrel{\mu^*}{\longrightarrow}[0,\infty],\quad A\cup S\mapsto\mu(A).\end{align}$$

Given an extended real-valued function $f:D_f(\subset X)\to[-\infty,\infty]$, if there exists a function $g:D_g\to[-\infty,\infty]$ s.t.

$D_f\Delta D_g$ is $\mu$-null,
$\{x\in D_f\cap D_g:f(x)\ne g(x)\}$ is $\mu$-null,

then we say $f=g$ a.e. (almost everywhere). If $D_g=X$ and $g$ is measurable w.r.t $(\mathcal{M},\mu)$, we say $f$ is $\mu$-a.e. measurable.
Let $\tilde{f}$ be any extended function of $f$ on $X$, my question is how to prove that
$$''f\text{ is a.e. }\mu\text{-null measurable} \Longleftrightarrow \tilde{f}\text{ is measurable w.r.t. } (\mathcal{M}^*,\mu^*)''$$

What have you tried?  Were are you stuck?

@Ramiro I don't know how to prove the proposition from right to left. For the proposition from left to right, I can consider the symmetric difference of the preimages of any open set in the extended real numbers with respect to some $\mu$-measurable function $g$ and $\tilde{f}$, respectively, to conclude that $\tilde{f}$ is $\mu^*$-measurable. However, I don't know how to construct a suitable $g$ for the reverse direction.

For the the "right-to-left" part: if all you know is that $f:D_f(\subset X)\to[-\infty,\infty]$ is an extended real-valued function, then the "right-to-left" part may be false. To prove the "right-to-left" part, you need to assume that $X \setminus D_f$ is a $\mu$-null set. Then, just take $\tilde{f}$ as the $g$.

@Ramiro yes, you were right, i need to add the condition "$X\setminus D_f$ is $\mu$-null" . If I take $g=\tilde{f}$, then any preimage of open sets are $\mu^*$ measurable sets, i.e. , unions of some $\mu$-measurable set and some $\mu$-null set, how to conclude that they can be $\mu$-measurable sets?

You are right, it is not just taking $\tilde{f}$ as $g$.

We already know that there is a sequence of simple functions that monotonically converges to any given measurable function. If the proposition holds for simple functions, let $\phi_{n} \to \tilde{f}$ as $n \to \infty$, and $\phi_n$ be a simple function, then there exists a measurable (with respect to $\mathcal{M}$) sequence $\psi_n = \phi_n$ except on a $\mu$-null set $E_n$.
To ensure the pointwise convergence of $\{\psi_n\}$, take $g \leftarrow \chi_{A} \psi_n$ as $n \to \infty$, where $A$ is a measurable set contained in the intersection of the complements of $E_n$s. Thus, $g$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{M}$ and $g = \tilde{f}=f$ almost everywhere.
Hence, we only need to prove the proposition for simple functions. Note that any indicator function $\chi_E$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{M}^*$ if $E \in \mathcal{M}^*$. Suppose $E = B \cup S$, where $B \in \mathcal{M}$ and $S$ is $\mu$-null, then $\chi_B$ is a measurable function with respect to $\mathcal{M}$ and $\chi_B = \chi_E$ almost everywhere. Therefore, any simple function satisfies the given proposition since it is a linear combination of indicator functions.
